# Problem with deployment to Vercel in Next.js

Tags: next.js, vercel, yandex-maps, mui-x, ckeditor4-react

I have Next.js project and I used @mui/material, ckeditor4-react and react-yandex-map. When I deploy project to Vercel I have errors with versions like
[image: error]

This is my package.json file

[image: package.json]